# High bandwidth ARP traffic on LAN interfaces

Tags: pfsense, arp

I'm using a PfSense Firewall with a few VLANs since over 4 years and in the last couple of days I've noticed network connectivity issues in two of the VLANs.

Using the web interface I'm seeing identical traffic curves for these two:

[image]

On the "Traffic graph" page of PfSense I'm seeing this traffic is coming via the broadcast IP?
[image]

With Wireshark I'm seeing thousands of ARP requests, most of them from the same IP

[image]

During these traffic spikes the internet is **very unresponsive** and even pinging devices in the same network (but different vlan) is resulting in about **40% Package loss**

I'm using a one-liner to see which IPs are having these battles and it seems that it's basically 3 IPs where the IP with the most packages is the pfsense **firewall itself** (10.11.11.18). 100,000 packages were recorded in just about 4 seconds.

```
# tcpdump -c 100000 -l -i em1.107 -n arp | egrep 'who-has' | cut -d ' ' -f 7 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n

100000 packets captured
113803 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel

8774 10.11.11.110,
8774 10.11.11.117,
69291 10.11.11.18,
```

A few more pointers:

1. The traffic spikes occur ~ 2 per minute but with no clear interval
2. Sometimes it works for hours without a problem
3. Sometimes the traffic spikes are ongoing for 2-5 minutes, most of the time just a few seconds
4. Traffic spikes are usually ~8MB/s but I saw them as high as 50MB/s
5. Both VLANs have rules that allow traffic from and to all other VLANs

Has anyone of you seen such a thing?

Comment: ARP is broadcast, so it will not cross from one VLAN to another VLAN. You quite possibly be getting a layer-2 loop that causes a broadcast storm. That can happen if spanning tree is disabled, and someone connects two interfaces in the same VLAN. I have also see some end devices that somehow create a broadcast storm because spanning tree is disabled on the access interfaces. For example, Windows can bridge (at one time it was a default) and we had people connecting personal laptops that caused this. disallowing BPDUs (shut down on BPDU reception) on access interfaces may fix it/identify port.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I've enabled broadcast storm control on the switch and limited it to 8kbs now the network will just slow down instead of breaking entirely. That gives me time to find the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it was a loop. A (non-managed) switch had a cable connected on two slots.

Thanks Ron for the pointers. Didn't think loops could cause arp-only traffic too

Comment: The loop is not _causing_ the ARP traffic, it is merely perpetuating and amplifying broadcasts, and ARP requests are broadcasts. A single ARP request on a network with a loop will have the ARP request sent to every interface, which will then receive it back because of a loop and resend it, over and over, until the loop is broken.